# JavaScript version of while True loop

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, loops

I wrote this bit of code

```py
while True:
   text = input('type here > ')
   print text
```

I've tried the below but it doesnt seem to be working

I'm having bit of a struggle trying to create a JavaScript version of it, since it seems js while loops constantly rerun but python seems to wait for input before rerunning. I am using the readline module to receive input from the console.

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

while (true) {
 rl.question('type here > ', text => {
       console.log(text)
    })
}
```

Is there something im getting wrong? Im fairly new to programming

Any solutions?

Comment: How are you prompting for input in your JavaScript code? And what JavaScript environment are you running in? (When you're having trouble with some code it's usually more helpful to share the code that _isn't_ working than the code that _is_.)

Comment: I used the readline module to get the input, I'll add the bit of code I have

Comment: Does this help?  https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/

Comment: It reruns constantly because `question` is an async method, so the loop iteration does not wait on it to continue. If you're new to Javascript, I would recommend you to check how async programming works in JS, since a fairly big part of JS projects rely on it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for getting a better grasp of it

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is get input from the console in JavaScript you can use NodeJS process.stdin the implementation below :

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let input = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    input += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    input = input.trim()
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.trim());

    // calling the function that works on the input
    doSomething();
});


function readInput() {
    return input[currentLine++];

}
```

Sample function to do something with what you get from the console

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log(readInput())
}
```